# What is the "active item slot"?

Tags: chrono-ark

I picked up an active item, but am unable to use it in battle. The prompt states "Place in the active item slot to use it", but there's no explanation of what this is or how to do it.

[image: Item helper text]

There's something to the right of the main item list that certainly looks like an "active item slot", but dragging the item onto it does nothing. It's also where the active relics are, so I can't tell if it truly is the active item slot, or just related to relics.

How do I use this item in battle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right clicking on an active item in the main inventory will move it to the Active equip slot. The item can't be unequipped, and switching in a different active item will destroy the old one.

Oddly, there is a tooltip that shows this, but only in battle, where it has no effect.